# Is it possible to trade Pokemon with other trainers?

Tags: pokemon-go

Is there a way to send or trade Pokemon from one account / trainer to another?

Comment: No, you cannot trade pokemon currently

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Didn't even see that question

Answer (score 1):

No, this is currently not a feature in the game.

However, this is forthcoming:

> [Pokémon Go will eventually allow players to trade Pokémon](http://www.theverge.com/2016/7/10/12139474/pokemon-go-trading-augmented-reality-niantic-ceo-john-hanke)
>
> CEO John Hanke recently told Business Insider that the game will eventually allow players to trade their Pokémon with their friends, just like in the halcyon Gameboy days.
>
> "It's kind of a core element," Hanke said.